# Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError) in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber

Ther versions i am using

Firefox : 60.0
Selenium webdriver: 3.11.0
Os: Ubuntu 14.04
framework : cucumber
Language: ruby
Jenkins: 2.131

I am trying to execute the cucumber from jenkins and it gives the below failure

```
Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
./features/support/env.rb:237:in `Before'
```

When i executed the same cucumber file in my terminal it is working fine. I also confirmed that both jenkins and my terminal user are same and in the same directory.

Not sure about the root cause and how to rectify it.

Comment: I'd look at whats going on in around the line meantion in that stacktrace (env.rb) and get more info on the error it seems to throw.
It seems selenium isn't starting properly in your jenkins environment. for example, can it find the driver executable?

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot Do you have any idea where i can i find the full error stacktrace. Will it be there in any log file. If yes can you suggest some log file where i can look into.

Comment: If jenkins/ruby doesnt provide you a stack trace (I thought they usually do - are you redirecting stdout?), perhaps add more logging yourself? I'd start looking in your `Before` hook - what's the exact line that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Adding DISPLAY=:5 before the cucumber command solved the issue.

```
  DISPLAY=:5 cucumber features/
```